# Uncheck box using jQuery after checking condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am using `.append` to append a new check box on a button click. On Click event is working but there is some problem with the code. Also,if the user clicks on the 11th checkbox, I have to display an error message and uncheck the checkbox. How can I do it using jQuery? Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jByt3/1/)
. And the code:

HTML:

```
    <button id="add">Add Checkbox</button>
    <div id="checkbox"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $("#add").on("click", function () {
        alert("Click Successful");
        var Row = $('<div id="checkbox"> </div>');
        Row.append('<input type="checkbox" id="Bike">Check Me');
    });
```

Comment: `var Row = $('<div id="checkbox"> </div>');` creates a new DOM element. It doesn't find an existing element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jByt3/4/)**

For Part I, Use this code to append.

`var row = $('#checkbox');` - **[Id based selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)**.

And not `$('<div id="checkbox"> </div>');` - It creates new DOM element.

```
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    alert("Click Successful");
    var Row = $('#checkbox');
    Row.append('<input type="checkbox" class="Bike">Check Me');
                   //                  ^ change ID to class to avoid duplicates
});
```

Note : `id="Bike"` is getting duplicated on each append. So, use `class="Bike"`

---

For part II, use `eq(10)` to get the 11th checkbox - **[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**.

And `:gt(9)` for greater than 10.

```
$(document).on('change','.Bike:gt(9)',function(){

    if(this.checked){                 //check if checked
          alert('greater than 10 checkbox');
          this.checked = false;       //uncheck the checkbox
    }
});
```

### [Full Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jByt3/12/)

Comment: How do I check condition greater than 10?

Comment: Updated. Check full demo. Use `:gt(9)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var Row = $('#checkbox'); // address the destination by id
Row.append('<input type="checkbox" class="Bike">Check Me'); // use class instead of id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for different ids n keep a count on number of textbox

```
    var count = 0;
$("#add").click(function(){
    var count = $('#checkbox input').length;
    if(count < 11) {
        $("#checkbox").append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+ (count+1) +'">Check Me');
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: I could add unlimited number of checkboxes.

Comment: remove if statement but dont remove count++

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. http://jsfiddle.net/jByt3/10/

```
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    alert("Click Successful");
    if ( $('#checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').length < 10 ) {
        $('#checkbox').append('<input type="checkbox" id="Bike">Check Me');
    }
});
```

Side notes:

When you want to use an id, you should call it this way.

```
$('#id')
```

When you want to use a class, you should call it this way.

```
$('.class')
```

Please do not use the whole html markup to reference the element.